# How to work with multiple GCC - LLVM and clang

Tags: gcc, llvm, clang, llvm-clang

In my box we have GCC 4.1.2 installed as root user but to compile LLVM and clang I needed a higher version of GCC. So I downloaded and **installed GCC 4.5.0 in my local directory**.

How can I make existing programs refer to GCC 4.5.0 libs and includes.

```
> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

> which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

> setenv PATH gcc-4.5.0/bin/gcc/gcc-4.5.0/bin:$PATH

> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.0
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

> which gcc
gcc-4.5.0/bin/gcc/gcc-4.5.0/bin/gcc
```

Is it that just setting the system PATH will help me or is there anything else I need to do for existing code to refer GCC 4.5.0 suite?

```
gcc-4.5.0/bin/gcc/gcc-4.5.0/> ls -l
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 prasad ppusers 4096 Jun 13 21:32 bin
drwxrwxr-x 3 prasad ppusers 4096 Jun 13 21:32 include
drwxrwxr-x 3 prasad ppusers 4096 Jun 13 21:32 lib
drwxrwxr-x 2 prasad ppusers 4096 Jun 13 21:32 lib64
drwxrwxr-x 3 prasad ppusers 4096 Jun 13 21:32 libexec
drwxrwxr-x 6 prasad ppusers 4096 Jun 13 21:32 share
```

Comment: I would recommend you put the path to your local copy of GCC _last_ in in `$PATH`, i.e. `export PATH=$PATH:/your/local/path`. The call your compiler with `gcc-4.5` instead. This way you can still build applications for the system, as well as your own applications.

Comment: But that is not the objective here at all. I need to compile the code with GCC 4.5.0 version only

Comment: Yes, you need to compile _your_ code with a specific version, but code compiled for the _system_ should be using the compiler supplied by the system. This is because there might be incompatibilities in the system tools otherwise. My suggestion can of course be combined with the answer by cobbal, so you set `PATH` as I suggest, and then do e.g. `CC=gcc-4.5 make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this varies greatly by your build system.

For make (and possibly other systems) the C compiler is specified in the `CC` variable, so you can just call

```
CC=/path/to/new/gcc make
```

if the project uses configure scripts from autoconf, you can use something similar

```
./configure CC=/path/to/new/gcc
```